# Not able to add UITapGestureRecognizer and UILongPressGestureRecognizer to a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uibutton

I am using the following code snippet to add the gesture recogniser :

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(attachImage))
    let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    cell.image.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    cell.image.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)

@objc func longPress(_ btn : UIButton) {
        selectedImageIndex = btn.tag
    }
@objc func attachImage(_ btn : UIButton) {
        selectedImageIndex = btn.tag
    }
```

I am getting the following error when I press the button

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2802ec000

Answer (score 2):

Change the functions as follows

```
@objc func longPress(_ sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if let btn = sender.view {
        selectedImageIndex = btn.tag
    }
}
@objc func attachImage(_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let btn = sender.view {
        selectedImageIndex = btn.tag
    }
}
```

And change gesture initialization as follows

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(attachImage(_:)))
let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(_:)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add gesture on `imageView` then you have to enable `isUserInteractionEnabled`.

```
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

And If you add gesture on `UIButton` then

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, #selector (tapGestureActionHandler(_:)))  //Tap function will call when user tap on button
    let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, #selector(longGestureActionHandler(_:)))  //Long function will call when user long press on button.
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    button.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    button.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
}

@objc func tapGestureActionHandler(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("Tap happend")
}

@objc func longGestureActionHandler(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    print("Long press")
}
```